# Java subtract two ints, result should be a minimum of zero

Tags: java

I want to subtract one integer from another, and the result should floor at 0. So 2 minus 4 should equal 0. I could just do

```
int result = x - y;
if (result < 0) result = 0;
```

But is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
int result = Math.max(0, x - y);
```

Answer (score 9):

While a lot of people are rushing out with `Math.max(...)` solutions, I'd like to offer a simple if statement.

```
if (y > x) {
  result = 0;
} else {
  result = x - y;
}
```

It is guaranteed to always return a result raised to 0, it doesn't require invoking an extra stack frame (entering the Math static function would), and it prevents underflow.

In the rare event that X is close to the minimum int, and y is sufficiently large enough, evaluating (x-y) would result in an underflow.  The result would be "too large" of a negative number to fit in an int's space and would therefore roll into a nonsense (and probably positive) answer.

By forcing the if statement to guarantee no underflow exists, this solution is also more correct than the `Math.max(...)` solutions.  However, most people don't care because they rarely deal with numbers that get close to causing overflows and underflows.

Comment: Actually, this is a less correct solution to the problem *as stated* by the OP.  Also, there's a good chance that Math.max is small enough that the JIT compiler will inline it.

Comment: @Stephen, the OP is subject to underflow just as is the Math.max() solution.  It is because you can't guarantee against underflow after you subtract, you have to check for it before you subtract.  Let X = Integer.MIN_INT and Y = 8, you will underflow (probably returning a positive number, which you will then treat as the answer).

Comment: I know that.  But the OP's question ... as stated ... requires that to happen.  It clearly says "subtract two numbers", not "find the difference between two numbers".  You have changed the problem.  This *could* be what the OP ultimately needs ... or not.

Answer (score 3):

Use ternary operator `?:`

```
int result = (x - y) > 0 ? (x - y) : 0;
```

Comment: Its the conditional operator... it just happens to be a ternary operator. Also this is no good if x or y is a function call.

Comment: @trinithis why do you say it is not good if the second and/or third operands are funtion calls?

Comment: @edalorzo: Because the functions would execute twice - unlikely to be desirable, and possibly causing a significantly bad side-effect.

Comment: @trinthis: It`s a conditional operator, but why not? At least it avoids the bug of your solution, and it might look more elegant. However: In Java, x and y can't be function calls.

Comment: @trinthis they would execute twice only if condition evaluates to true in this case. At any rate I see your point and agree, although in this case is irrelevant since neither of the operands use metod calls. By the way the JLS also refer to this operator as a ternary conditional operator (page 526).